# Is it possible to use a variable within a session to use in other pages?

Tags: php, session, variables

I'm making a site for buying/selling and i have a hard coded userID that is made, now i would like to use this in other sessions, how can i do this?

Here is a code snippet:

```
    //register.php - (assuming the below is in php brackets)
    function unique_id()
    {
         return substr(str_shuffle("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"), 0, 6);
    }

    $cID = unique_id();

    session_start();
    $_SESSION[$cID] = $cID;

    //listing.php - (assuming the below is in php brackets & page that i'm trying to store data to)
    session_start();
    $cID = $_SESSION[$cID];
```

When i open listing.php even after making a session with register.php, i get "Notice: Undefined variable: cID". Does anyone know what I can do about this? or does anyone have any other ideas for a function to create a unique customer ID that i can put in a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You session variable key should be a string, not the name of the variable you are assigning.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['cID'] = $cID;

//listing.php - (assuming the below is in php brackets)

session_start();
$cID = $_SESSION['cID'];
```

Comment: when i try that, i get "Notice: Undefined index: cID"

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that if your session_start() is on both pages before any output is sent to the browser.

Comment: I've only tried session variables with input from html forms, this is the first time using it with a function, do you think it's the function i've used? as there is no input from the user, the system does it all?

Comment: The function you posted above won't affect your sessions at all. In fact, I don't see anything in the code you've posted that would cause this issue.

Comment: hmm, i tried deleting the session code in the register.php and re-entering it and did the same with listing.php and it works with your method! thanks for your help :)

Comment: i would up-vote your answer, but i'm not at the rep level yet, but this did help :)

Comment: @TomKenneth I think you're there now. :) You can also click the green check mark under the voting arrows if my answer solved your problem.